# What are DecisionTree.trainClassifier parameters in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm studying Spark MLlib.
While studying DecisionTree, I see following DecisionTree.trainClassifier usage example.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree._
val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainData, 7, Map[int, int](), "gini", 4, 100)
```

There are 6 parameters here, I don't understand the 3rd(Map), 5th(4) and 6th(100) parameters.

Google says they are categorical feature, lambda and alpha.
Can anyone explain them a bit better?

need your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the signature of the function is:

> def trainClassifier(input: RDD[LabeledPoint], numClasses: Int, categoricalFeaturesInfo: Map[Int, Int], impurity: String, maxDepth: Int, maxBins: Int): DecisionTreeModel

and in [spark DecisionTree source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/DecisionTree.scala)  you can see the description of the parameters:

**categoricalFeaturesInfo**

Map storing arity of categorical features. An entry (n -> k) indicates that feature n is categorical with k categories indexed from 0: {0, 1, ..., k-1}.

**maxDepth**

Maximum depth of the tree (e.g. depth 0 means 1 leaf node, depth 1 means  1 internal node + 2 leaf nodes).  (suggested value: 5)

**maxBins**

Maximum number of bins used for splitting features (suggested value: 32)

Comment: It's not suggested 32 for maxBins, the default value is (=32)  But should be greater or equal to the maximum number of categories for categorical features.

Answer (score 5):

**3rd:**
categoricalFeaturesInfo:Any features not in this map are treated as continuous.

For example, Map(0 -> 2, 4 -> 10) specifies that feature 0 is binary (taking values 0 or 1) and that feature 4 has 10 categories (values {0, 1, ..., 9}). Note that feature indices are 0-based: features 0 and 4 are the 1st and 5th elements of an instance’s feature vector.

Map[Int,Int]  means that all features are numerical type.

**5th:**
it is easy to understand,it is the (max) depth of the tree.

**6th**:
maxBins: Number of bins used when discretizing continuous features.

Increasing maxBins allows the algorithm to consider more split candidates and make fine-grained split decisions. However, it also increases computation and communication.

Note that the maxBins parameter must be at least the maximum number of categories.

**YOU CAN REFER TO THE BOOK "Adcaned Analytics with Spark"(chapter 4.8-4.10) FOR MORE DETAILS.**

Comment: Hi @s yh. Does "Map[Int,Int]" also mean that the user is passing all the columns as features to the Decision Tree algorithm ?

Comment: @JKC I think it may be not.It just tell the algorithm which features is ‘categoricalFeatures’.It may consist all of the features and it can also consist some of the features and it can consist none of the features...I think so..